# Can I ask this question on the main site: "Where's this parking lot in front of a white building in the US?"

Tags: discussion

Because my first two questions here were closed and downvoted, I just wanted to run this draft by you before posting on main site. If this is OK, I'll post it.

I cut out my dad's head from this picture, but does anyone know where this is? He's confident it was taken in the US a few years ago.

[image]

Comment: no further details at all? Which states did he visit? Cities?

Comment: Are you serious? The background is some extremely generic apartment blocks, so overexposed (or maybe just faded by time) that you can't see where the building ends and the sky begins. I'd struggle to recognise my own house on a picture of that quality.

Comment: @markmayo he can't remember. sorry! just forget about this if there isn't enough detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Willeke ♦ in that this question is probably on-topic but so short on details that it is unlikely to be seen as interesting or useful by anyone else and is also unlikely to draw the attention of anyone who might actually recognize the place. Since there's few details other than the fact that it is in the USA (a stupendously large country), it's not clear how someone who didn't already know more details would be able to *start* researching this.

For the reasons above, I probably would refrain from voting to close but downvote it for being poorly-researched and just not that useful.

Answer (score 7):

Not against the rules to ask where a picture was taken but it has so few recognizable details that I think it has no use to post it.