# Area 51 Proposal for Where is This, Identifying Places?

Tags: discussion, scope

1. Has anyone tried to start an Area 51 proposal just for identifying where a picture was taken?

   To separate https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locate-this, https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/where-on-earth, https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this from Travel?
2. Would this proposal be supported enough? They work well with Stack exchange's Q & A model, but  Area 51 requirements are pretty harsh.

And websites like where-is-this.com, reddit.com/r/whereisthis, r/WWTT/ stand alone too.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not aware of a specific proposal, but recently somebody asked [a similar question on Area 51 Discussions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32288/151554), but about identification questions in general. I'll quote the relevant part of my answer there:

> The main problem with identification questions is that they are seldom useful for other users than the asker. This interferes with Stack Exchange's aim to be a high-quality library of questions and answers useful for everybody interested in topic X.

So I agree with "They work well with Stack exchange's Q & A model" only that they are *technically* supported by the Stack Exchange Q&A software, but not by its mission. It's great that there are other sites on Internet which do work well for these kind of questions; that's just an example of several types of 'knowledge networks' complementing each other.

Comment: Thanks. Just a thought. I didn't see that similar question on Area 51.

Comment: Does this answer then suggest that travel.se should be less inclined to entertain these questions? https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/when-where-in-the-world-is-overdone-or-collides-with-wanta

Comment: I have to say, identification questions are *incredibly* useful over on the scifi SE, they typically get a lot of views, and regularly people end up asking about the same story/book/movie/game etc.  They are really interesting to read through as well.  But the same cannot be said for all SE topics, thats for sure.

Comment: What happens if you propose an Area 51 for picture ID, but proposal gets closed or shut down? Does your account get in trouble?

Comment: @KristenL. no, not at all. But I'm not sure it would be well-received, see e.g. [Please someone propose for an identification.stackexchange.com site](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32288/151554)